# UINavigationController doesn't initialise root view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have an issue with `UINavigationController`.

I have a container view (designed in .xib file). Also, I have a view controller.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

[self.containerView addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Because of reasons I am not aware of, view controller's `self.viewController` view is not initialised (method `- viewWillAppear` is not being called).

I wonder, why method `- viewWillAppear`is not called and how to change that?

Comment: how do you think adding it as subview initialises the view ?

Comment: I think you should add self.view insted of self.containerView. may it's wrong

Comment: @Mr.T adding subview is not causing this issue. When I add `[self.containerView addSubview:self.viewController.view];` it works fine, because it just adds subview as it is and `self.viewController` is responsible for methods calling.

Comment: @SandyPatel No, I am using a container view. In my situation it is common practice. But the problem is that navigation controller doesn't initialise his root view controller.

Answer (score -1):

When a view called first when the view created

- viewDidLoad called

but 
 - viewWillAppear/- viewDidAppear not called

when when navigation controller push another controller and back again then viewWillAppear cal.

Comment: Well, it is not true... Anyway, `- viewDidAppear` is not called too.

Comment: FYI when view appears all the three(willAppear,DidAppear,DidLoad) methods will surely get called.

Answer (score -1):

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.TestController];

[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Comment: My issue has nothing in common with `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method...

Comment: so u need navigationController on Perticular ViewController? You just Implement this code may be it's solve your problem. please check it one time then after tell me if any problem.

Comment: I have to add navigation controllers view in specific container view. If I am doing like `[self.containerView addSubview:view.controller.view]` everything goes fine. But, I need navigation hierarchy in my situation, so thats why I am adding `UINavigationController`. In my given example I see a navigation controller (navigation bar), but I don't see view controller inside...